# Чем это какая часть речи

Tags: морфология

В предложении "О чем вы спорите?" Чем является какой частью речи?

Answer (score 2):

Часть речи - местоимение. Разряд -вопросительное. Начальная форма - что.

Comment: А почему существительное? В Грамматике-80 говорится, что это местоимение-существительное (я,ты, кто, что и др.)

Comment: Оё-ёй, конечно, местоимение. Описка, прошу прощения. Исправляю.

Answer (score 1):

Это местоименное существительное, которое по разряду значений принадлежит к вопросительным местоимениям.